# Problem with restarting MySQL server installed through aptitude on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I'm using Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (10.04) and installed MySQL server through aptitude. 
The installation automatically added a user called mysql (it didn't exist in /etc/passwd file at the beginning and it exists there after the installation.) and started MySQL server.

Then I needed to modify my.cnf (in order to enable remote access to the MySQL server). 
When I restarted MySQL server with

$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart

it hang. But displaying processes by "top" command in another terminal indicated that MySQL server was running with root user. But my.cnf clearly sets

user = mysql

Then I tried

$ sudo service mysql restart

And the result was even worse. It didn't start the MySQL server at all.

As far as I remember, I have never encountered such a problem in the previous versions of Ubuntu.

So my questions are:

1. How can I start MySQL server with a user called mysql in Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (10.04)?
2. Which is the most reliable way to start MySQL server in Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (10.04),

   /etc/init.d/mysql start

   or

   service mysql start

   or

   start mysql

   and what is the difference?

Thank you in advance.

Tadatoshi

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/init.d/xxxx start` is used to start services using SysV init scripts. Ubuntu uses *upstart* instead of SysV init and the init scripts are getting converted to native upstart jobs. Usually the init scripts for converted jobs display a warning and call *upstart*.

`start xxxx` is used with services using *upstart* and doesn't work with services using SysV init.

`service xxxx start` automatically chooses the right one, so it's safe to always use *service*

As far as I know MySQL has been converted to use upstart in 10.04

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, Florian and user46528,

Based on the Florian's answer, I started to use only "service mysql start".

Then following user46528's answer, I started to investigate the problem.

In short, it turned out the problem was setting bind-address to the IP address of the server in my.cnf.

The key issues I found are:

- If Amazon EC2 is used, bind-address must be set to the private IP address.
- Once "service mysql start" fails because of the problem of bind-address in my.cnf in Ubuntu Lucid Lynx, no matter what is done to resolve it, it keeps hanging. I needed to set the bind-address to a correct IP address and reboot the Ubuntu.

The more detailed explanation of what happened is:

1. I'm using Amazon EC2, which has public IP address and private IP address for each instance, in my case Ubuntu Lucid Lynx instance.
2. With the default bind-address setting in my.cnf, which is bind-address = 127.0.0.1 (localhost), "service mysql stop" and "service mysql start" worked.
3. In my.cnf, I changed the bind-address to the Amazon EC2 public IP address. Then "service mysql stop" worked but "service mysql start" hang.
4. In /var/log/mysql/error.log, I saw "[ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address".
5. In my.cnf, I changed the bind-address to the Amazon EC2 private IP address. Then both "service mysql stop" and "service mysql start" hang.
6. In my.cnf, I changed the bind-address back to the default 127.0.0.1. Still both "service mysql stop" and "service mysql start" hang.
7. In my.cnf, I changed the bind-address to the Amazon EC2 private IP address. Then I rebooted the Linux server (by Amazon EC2 reboot command). Then MySQL server started correctly with the user called mysql.
8. "sudo netstat -na" displayed the port 3306 (port for MySQL server) with the private IP address with the State "LISTEN".
9. Accessing the port from another Amazon EC2 instance by "telnet *private-ip* 3306" indicated that it's connected.

Thank you again for your helps. Without them, I was not able to resolve the problem.

Sincerely, 
Tadatoshi

Answer (score 1):

if it didn't start, i.e. ps ax | grep mysql   doesn't show safe_mysqld and mysqld running, take a look at /var/lib/mysql/hostname.err  (where hostname is your machine's hostname) and it has a somewhat detailed log.  restart in the default package does a stop, start, but, I wonder if mysqld isn't actually stopping.

/etc/init.d/mysql stop

ps ax|grep mysql   (make sure there are no processes running)

/etc/init.d/mysql start

now, if you are looking at the processes, safe_mysqld runs as root, the mysqld process runs as mysql.  If mysqld crashes, safe_mysqld loops and tries to restart mysql.  Is safe_mysqld or mysqld the process you saw running as root?

Answer (score 0):

The default my.cnf says `port = 3306` and `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`. If you don't have a loopback interface configured, this binding will fail.

To create a loopback interface:

`ifconfig lo up 127.0.0.1`